# Inserting and sniffing vendor-specific information into beacon frames with Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, wifi, android-wifi

I'm creating an Android app that serves as a Wifi AP. I'd like to insert data into the vendor-specific information field in the beacon frame. I'd then have another app that listens for these beacon frames and extracts the data from them. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While not having much experience with android, generally the availability of this kind of functionality is dependent on the chipset drivers of the OS. Thus, I suspect that this is not possible with android SDK, but with NDK it might be.

Microsoft research had a publication about similar idea 5 years ago:
http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/73482/beaconstuffing.pdf.
This paper might be useful to read as a background for the application.